# Superclass mismatch

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I am trying to do inheritance program as follows:

```
class P1
end

class P2
end

class A < P1
end

class A < P2
end
```

When I ran this program, I got an error as follows:

```
superclass mismatch for class A (TypeError)
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are defining a class, it by default inherits `Object`. If you make it a subclass of any *other* class, then it will inherit that *other* class. But this subclassing can be done only when you are defining your custom class for the first time using the keyword `class` or method `Class::new`. Once you defined it, when you re-open your class for the second time and on, you wouldn't be allowed to CHANGE its *super class*.

In your example:

```
# here you are defining your new class A, so you can make it now a subclass of
# the parent class of any, like P1
class A < P1
end

# here you are reopeing the same class A. Now you are not again allowed to change the 
# super class of it, which is P1.
class A < P2
end
```

What you can do is, make `P1` and `P2` modules, then *include* them inside `A` anytime you want to during the course of your program.

Comment: I edited the question because there were so many noise in it. So the particular method definitions disappeared from it. Perhaps you might want to delete that. It will make your answer more to the point.

Comment: Method calls are irrelevant to the error. The error is raised at the moment of `class A < P2`. It is rather confusing to put it in the question.

Comment: @sawa Agreed. I also have edited. Thanks for telling me the change of the post's content.